# Should I reapply for a job after a rejection if the job posting gets announced again?

Tags: applications, rejection

I applied for a job which was posted on careers 2.0.
They rejected me with the reason, that they have found already some one to take the position. The posting was also taken out from careers 2.0.

Yesterday they posted the job again on careers 2.0.
Now I'm asking my self: Is it worth to apply again?
On the one hand, if they really already had some one when they got my application, I should act now.
But on the other hand, if they just rejected it with that reason for not beeing rude, it could be kind of ridiculous, and I got be kept in mind as that. That would be worse, when they remember me after I got more experience and try to apply again for that company.
(I really would love to work for them)

So I ask now: Can I take in general a rejection by that reasoning serious? So It is worth Reapply for the reposted job, as I'm now one of the first that applies.
Or is it more likely that they will say somethink like "Hey Jim, look: its that guy again, he really didn't get it."?

What could make them more likely to remember me in the future connected with a bad impressions, in the case I apply in some years a third time then.

Comment: When asking "is it worth it" keep in mind that all you're proposing is writing an email. So it is not a big waste even if they don't respond. But on the other hand, they may think, "Oh, this person is really interested in the position" and therefore leave a positive impression. Make sure you mention that you applied before as mentioned in the comments already. -- One clarification. How long has it been since the last rejection email and now?

Comment: @Brandin: With "worth it" I'm regarding to the maybe bad impression. the rejection mail was delivered about 2 months ago. my last application is 4 months ago.

Comment: Well, if you don't apply to them, is that a *good* impression? If it was 4 months ago that you applied, I think that's long enough. Just let them know that you applied some months ago and noticed a new listing available now and would like to apply for the new, similar listing.

Comment: I would never bother applying for a job for which I was recently rejected. They didn't want you then, why would they now? It's just a waste of time. If it was 2 or 3 years later then OK, you can acquire a lot of new skills, but not 4 months.

Comment: @TheMathemagician It seems like that would depend on the reason you were rejected. If they were honest about the reason - they found somebody else to fill the position - then that doesn't necessarily mean you weren't a *good* candidate. It just means you weren't the *best* candidate. That person could have ended up being unsuited for the job despite interviewing well, or decided not to accept the offer, or decided during a trial period the job wasn't for them, or it's a similar/identical position that they need to fill with another candidate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"I am interested in the position offered. I want to mention that when I  contacted you a couple of weeks earlier about an identical position, that you had replied that the position had been filled. I am reaching out to you again on the presumption that another identical position opened up and that you had no issue with my qualifications in the previous go-round." In other words, you are telegraphing your punches :)

Answer (score 8):

With your follow-up comments about the timing (which you will hopefully edit into your original question), I would encourage you to apply again.

There may be more than one position, or the closing negotiations with the selected candidate may have failed after several delays.  You don't have enough knowledge about the context to have a reason for not applying again.

The worst you're going to get is that they will decline you, again, which puts you in no worse position than you are now.

Answer (score -1):

> like "Hey Jim, look: its that guy again, he really didn't get it."?

Yes, like that.

If they lost your resume or tell you *whatever* to get rid of you it's best to take your experience (interviewing) and apply it somewhere fresh. If you look at enough ADs you will sometimes see "If you were rejected within the past 6-8 months **don't** reapply.".

Everyone I know applies across the street or down the road at the competition. If they knew that they can't afford to lose a talented person like yourself to the competitors they would have **at least said** "We certainly are glad you applied but there is someone else whom is a better match, we hope we can call you in the future; we'll keep your resume on file.".

They have your old resume with the interviewer's notes, they don't need a new one; you need at least a year doing something that will impress them or a few years more experience; unless it was the money, next year or three you want less or they'll be in a better position to offer more.

**Don't linger** after you're told, no one likes that.

If you're in charge at a competitor in a couple of years they are losing double.

If you **don't** reapply ever then decades from now they'll have lost more gross income than you would have made there during your stay (especially if you only end up staying several years).

You want to substitute their good judgment with your own?, march down there, because they won't like that either.

Accept the wisdom or the mistake of the company.

You're asking "should I tell them they are wrong or forgetful"; I might but I wouldn't advise you to do that without more info, but then why work there unless it's your former interviewer's job.