# How to approach via cover letter while re-applying for a job that I have been rejected from?

Tags: rejection

So they say "Third time is a charm" but I am not quite sure how to approach this time. A little bit of hiring process detail - this public company gives the written test to its applicants. Top three candidates are interviewed and one is picked. I have had tried for the two levels of the same position :lower level in March 2013 and senior level in December 2015. Both times I passed the written test with a score that placed me at #1 for the three candidate to be interviewed. Both times I got rejected after the interview.

In May 2014 I got hired at a challenging position that I like, in a better company and with better pay. But commute of 800 mi per week is my issue. I am willing to work for less money but doing the same thing that I love and have experience in.

As far as I remember I interviewed well in Dec 2015 for the senior level position, in fact they were talking to me as if I were one of them already. They remembered me from 2013 interview, talked about my 'then' job as well as attending a user conf with them. It was very informal interview. I wrote thank you letters after the interview. I also wrote an email (asking for feedback on the interview) to both members of the interview penal after I received the rejection letter. But no response. One of them I have as LinkedIn contact but I never contacted her regarding any of these positions.

Now the lower level of the position that I tried in 2013 is advertised again. I won't mind going through the hiring process again, but before I do I need advice on the best approach to this so I get hired. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Besides Vietni's response below, if you search this site, there are tons of other questions answer with the same topic. Have you read them all?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44364/should-i-reapply-for-a-job-after-a-rejection-if-the-job-posting-gets-announced-a?rq=1

Comment: @Alex Thank you! I have been searching and reading. At this company I mentioned 'who you know' seems to matter a lot than 'what you know'. i just wanted an approach up front that Vietni explained beautifully. Hopefully they do not waste their and my time if they already have someone in mind.

Answer (score 4):

In your cover letter:

Tell them that you interviewed with them twice and between each interview, your qualifications simply got better and stronger.

Tell them that since May 2014, you have been working at company XXX as yyy. You love the job, enjoy the challenges, like your co-workers and the management but you don't like the commute, whose length is cutting into your professional development time.

Tell them that you are writing them again because you are interested in working for them as a result of having previously interviewed with them. In fact, you liked them even more after the second interview.

Tell them what you can do for them, what you want to do for them and hopefully, that's enough motivation for them to call you in for an interview.

Comment: The only trouble with this is explaining applying for a junior position when it was a senior position last time.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I have no idea. What's a junior position in company A might be considered senior in company B. It is clear that the OP has experience and he is applying as someone with experience. I'd let the prospective employer to sort it out and then the OP and the prospective employer to work it out.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Thank you! That is what I have been looking for. It is an IT position, it is possible that they moved up the junior to senior position. that explains my rejection. I won't find that out until I go through it once again. They know my desperation looking for a job near my home. Thank you once again!

Comment: Hi Vietnhi, I agree about the inaccuracy of comparing titles across different companies, but in this case it is within the same company, so it is a reasonable comparison.  I think @PhilipKendall's point is relevant in this specific case.