# How do I apply again to a company where I was rejected?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, cover-letter, reinterviewing

I applied for a very interesting job last year and unfortunately, I didn't get it. I did the first interview with HR, the second with Head Of Risk Management, and went well. I had the final interview with Managing Partner. The feedback from the hiring committee was generally positive:

> Thank you for completing the tests and for the overall dedication to
>   our recruitment process. We appreciate your interest in our company
>   and we were positively impressed by the drive you have for taking new
>   challenges forward – there is absolutely no doubt about it!
>   **Unfortunately**, we cannot offer you a position. Both Messrs. XXX and XXX truly enjoyed meeting you and finding more about your
>   experience. The interviews gave them a good insight into your skills
>   and capabilities and your application was thoroughly analyzed by the
>   Management. ...

A nearly identical job has been posted recently, and I want to apply, and as I have gained some experience that I can use directly to support my application. However, it has only been a year, so my experience level is still not as high as it could be.

How do I address the rejection from the last time I applied and describe the experience I've gained?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to approach applying for a position that I was rejected for before?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/101043/how-to-approach-applying-for-a-position-that-i-was-rejected-for-before)

Comment: “`How do I address the rejection from the last time I applied and describe the experience I’ve gained?`” You don’t need to talk about your previous engagement. Pretend that you’ve never interviewed with them in the past.

Comment: Sounds like they liked you. It could simply be you didn't get it because they liked someone else better and gave them the job. The good news is you know you won't be competing with that person this time around if you were to apply again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply.

Your feedback was good. Quite possible you were the 2nd best out of 50 applicants, or you were one of the two best and they threw a coin because they couldn’t hire both. It sounds like they would have hired you if that other person hadn’t been there.

And quite possible the person they hired left, or they have more work and need a second person now. I’d mention that I applied before, they might take a shortcut like doing three interviews together or in sequence, assuming that you will pass them since you passed last time. Mentioning it shows you have confidence in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email to the person who sent to you the interview feedback email mentioning you updated your skills and your resume and ready to apply again. I think you have an opportunity to apply again because they didn't reject you from the first or second interview that's mean you were shortlisted and they compare your profile with the other candidates.

Answer (score -1):

Just apply.

I don't think they say you lack experience.

So, apply as normal and add the experience you have gained in the interim emphasizing that which is directly relevant.

Good luck.